# Stackdriver Monitoring : custom metric issue

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I got a problem with the scalling of my custom metric in Stackdriver Monitoring. Moreover, data of my custom metric doesn't appear in the VALUE column.

I have set up a custom metric based on Cloud Composer logs, in order to retrieve data in the textPayLoad field.

My custom metric appears in Stackdriver Monitoring

I expect values of my custom metric to be at the right scale for the Y-axis.

Comment: Can you share details on how did you set the custom metric?

Comment: @yyyyahir I chose 'integer' for Label Type, 'textPayLoad' for Field name, my regex is (\d+\z) and i succeed to retrieve the right data in my logs.
Units is set to 1 and Type is 'counter' but can't be changed (grayed out field)

Comment: Do you have any details on how to replicate? Since custom metrics can be set in different ways, it'd help.